# Fill the fields of lightbox's form with json data

Tags: php, jquery, json, lightbox

I have a form that loads into a lightbox panel and a json response from a php script.
So im trying to load the data from json in the fields of form but nothing happens. Neither an error nor a result.

Here is some code:

Form:

```
<form id="FORM" name="newUserForm">
                <br>
                <label for="username" style="padding-right:35px;">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  style="margin-right:35px;">
                <label for="email" style="padding-right:35px;">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" id = "email" name="email" value="" ><br><br>
                <label for="password" style="padding-right:40px;">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
                <label for="repeatpassword">Repeat Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" style="margin-right:35px;">
                <label for="submitBt" id="submitEditUser" style="background-color:black;color:white;font-weight:bold;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;">Submit</label>
            </form>
```

Javascript:

```
var user = user_id;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: "/op/controller.php",
        data: { method: "editUser", user_id: user },
        contentType : ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        dataType : "json" ,
        success : function(json){
            $('#lightbox-background').fadeIn(300); 
            $('#lightbox-panel').fadeIn(300).load('forms/editUserForm.php');
            $('#username').val = json.username;
        }
    });
```

I have also tried with getElementById and populate but nothing happened.

Is there any idea why this problem exists? Maybe its because of the lightbox?

In addition i want to say that the html form exists in to the forms/editUserForm.php file.

Thanks.

Comment: `forms/editUserForm.php` should be `forms/newUserForm.php` (in the javascript part) surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the last command in the callback of load() and also the new value of #username must be passed as argument in val() like this

```
var user = user_id;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    url: "/op/controller.php",
    data: { method: "editUser", user_id: user },
    contentType : ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    dataType : "json" ,
    success : function(json){
        $('#lightbox-background').fadeIn(300); 
        $('#lightbox-panel').fadeIn(300).load('forms/editUserForm.php', function(){
           $('#username').val(json.username);
        });
    }
});
```